# Passing on a netty ByteBuf (Asynchronous)

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, netty

I have setup a TCP server using Netty. Now I need to transfer the input of the TCP server (which is a ByteBuf **stream** from produced by the channel thread) to a separate application thread and I want to do this in a asynchronous fashion where the channel thread writes onto a buffer stream and the application buffer reads from the thread.

I don't want to use the ByteBuf itself as I need to call msg.release() on it and I don't want the channel thread to be waiting for the msg to be consumed by the application thread. Also I can't have the application have its own channel handler.

What data structure in Java should I use that would allow such for my purpose? Is my approach correct or could I use the functionalities provisioned by Netty. InputStreams and OutputStreams also seem the way to do it but wouldn't the channel be waiting if I use them?

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    // Copy the msg's byte[] into a buffer stream and make the application read from the buffer stream


    ((ByteBuf) msg).release(); 
}
```

Comment: The advantage of netty bytebuffers is that they can be pooled, meaning no objects need to be removed by the garbage collector, even if your program is transferring data at 100 MB/s speeds. The objects need to be released to allow for this system

Comment: True, but how could I use them for my purpose? that is: get the information from the buffers and pass them on to the another thread while releasing the buffer in the mean time

Comment: Why can't you pass the `ByteBuf` to the application thread and either have the application thread release it or provide a callback that your application thread will call when it is done its work so that you can separate concerns?

Comment: I am actually coming to the same conclusion. My channel would write into 1 bytebuf and my application would consume from the same buffer through a separate thread. As I have 2 buffers one for read and one for write, things should go smoothly. When I write the bytes into the bytebuf, I'll release the msg. So something like: 'sharedBud.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);'

One thing that I'm concerned with is whether a copy would happen or is the actual data handled through pointers in ByteBuf.